# Get values from json_encode with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I insert several(`array`) value with `json_encode` in one row from database table, now want echo they as order with jquery.

This is output from my PHP code:

```
[{
    "guide": null,
    "residence": [{
        "name_r": "jack"
    }, {
        "name_r": "jim"
    }, {
        "name_r": "sara"
    }],
    "residence_u": [{
        "units": ["hello", "how", "what"],
        "extra": ["11", "22", "33"],
        "price": ["1,111,111", "2,222,222", "3,333,333"]
    }, {
        "units": ["fine"],
        "extra": ["44"],
        "price": ["4,444,444"]
    }, {
        "units": ["thanks", "good"],
        "extra": ["55", "66"],
        "price": ["5,555,555", "6,666,666"]
    }]
}]
```

I want as(output):

> `jack`
>  `hello` & `11` & `1,111,111`
>  `how` & `22` & `2,222,222`
>  `what` & `33`
>   & `3,333,333,`

> `jim`
>  `fine` & `44` & `4,444,444`

> `sara`
>  `thanks` & `55` & `5,555,555`
>  `good` & `66` & `6,666,666`

How is it?

Comment: @Matt Ball - What is the problem? What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

- you already know how make the ajax request that fetches this information from your PHP script
- there is always one element in the top-level array (if not, you could add one more level of iteration)
- by output you mean access the corresponding elements - I've put in calls to `console.log` but you could `alert()` or put into a DOM element or whatever

you could do something like this in jQuery (here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/erq3d/) without the network part. You'll see the output in your console)

```
var data = response[0]; //response is the data received by the jQuery ajax success callback
var residences = data.residence;
var residence_u = data.residence_u;

$.each(residences, function(index, val){
    var name = val.name_r;
    console.log(name);

    var info = residence_u[index]; //get the corresponding residence_u element

    $.each(info.units, function(index, val){
        var unit = val;
        var extra = info.extra[index];
        var price = info.price[index];
        console.log( val + " & " + extra + " & " + price);
    });
});
```

Comment: When i want use from your code, it in my code not worked. see my full code: http://pastebin.com/Rmt1797X i want append result in `<div class="tooltip">'+append here+'</div>` in `$.each(data[0].residence_u, function...`

Comment: @EmmyCharles What doesn't work exactly? Please consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also note that an `id` can't legally have `,`s in it - you're doing that when you use 'units` as the `id`.